# Run all Flutter tests with detailed info in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, unit-testing

How to run all Flutter tests at once from Android Studio UI and get a nice overview of all tests passed?
Possibly grouped by test files and groups (like Maven does in IntelliJ).

### Setup

This is my test file structure that includes 4 tests

[image]

### What I have tried

I have tried adding a configuration to run "all test in a directory", that does test all the tests but the output isn't as detailed as I wanted. It is missing individual test reports.

[image]

### Result

Doesn't show detailed info of what happened in tests and Test Results expand arrow is empty

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault there is a toggle to show passed test.
[image]